# SQL-server simple insert statement very slow - full scan of columnstore index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, ssms

[UPDATE at the Buttom!]

I am in quite a pickle. After insertion of some extra lines in my database, suddenly a simple insert statement has become very slow (>30 seconds per row).

My insert statement is simply:

```
Insert into insertview (column1, column2, ..., column5) VALUES (value1, ..., value5)
```

When looking at the execution plan it says: "Scan a columnstore index, entirely or only a range. Actual number of rows: 92.000.000"

This makes me suspect there is some issue with this columnstore index. Can any of you help me proceed any further? Is there something i can do to fix this?

Best regards.

[Update!]
I tried asking this question in a much better question instead and got an answer!
[How to: Change actual execution method from "row" to "batch" - Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550683/how-to-change-actual-execution-method-from-row-to-batch-azure-sql-server)

Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: Is `insertview`, as the name implies, in fact, a view? And is there anything in the definition of said view that might explain this?

Comment: insertview is in fact a view. And it was after adding additional rows to one of the three tables in the view that began stalling. 

However, I am not smart enough to see how these new rows should alter the efficiency of my insert statement. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: So, if the view has 92M rows now, and that your question *implies* you didn't insert many, that when it was "fast" it still returned closed to 92M rows?

Comment: Yeah, i inserted ~1000 rows. 
And yes, it was "fast" i.e. operable, in my test environment i am inserting thousands of rows in ~1 second.

In the test environment the same index returns just 1 row in the execution plan.

Thanks for spending your time thinking about this.

Comment: Is there an instead-of <insert> trigger on the view?

Comment: Yes there is! @SMor

Comment: So now is the time to go ask the person who wrote that trigger for help. Or post the trigger code (and the ddl for the tables involved, the view, and some sample data).

Comment: Thank you so much @SMor, sadly, I was hired and took over this project from a consulent firm. So I have noone to ask. I will post it here, and it it's too much. I understand. Just so very happy for you to have pointed me this far.